# Need row wise data in columns wise from select statement

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

Need row wise data from an account table into columns wise data.
I would need a select statement or function that would do this.

Account Function Table

```
Client  Acct    Function    Value

OK  OK123   Is_Human    Y
OK  OK144   Is_Human    N
OK  OK123   Is_Live Y
OK  OK144   Is_Live Y
VV  VV553   Is_Human    N
VV  VV510   Is_Human    Y
```

Account Table

```
Client  Acct    Acct_name

OK  OK123   OK123_Pnb
OK  OK144   OK144_Bnb
VV  VV553   VV553_Vnb
VV  VV510   VV510_Vpk
```

I have tried using listagg but could not achieve the desired result

```
select * from Account where client=OK
Expected output
Client  Acct    Acct_name Is_Human Is_Human_value Is_Live Is_live_value

OK  OK123   OK123_Pnb Y    Yes            Y   Active
OK  OK144   OK144_Bnb N    No             N   Inactive

select * from Account where client=VV
Expected output
Client  Acct    Acct_name Is_Human Is_Human_value Is_Live Is_live_value

VV  VV553   VV553_Vnb Y    Yes      
VV  VV510   VV510_Vpk N    No
```

Comment: what is Client Acct Function Value and Client Acct Acct_name, is it table name? If yes what is table structure ?

Comment: They are two table ,account function has all the list of characteristics say gender,country,region etc on row wise ,but on the output i am expecting that to be in columnar data which would be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    CLIENT,
    ACCT,
    ACCT_NAME,
    CASE
        WHEN IS_HUMAN IS NULL THEN 'N'
        ELSE IS_HUMAN
    END AS IS_HUMAN,
    CASE
        WHEN IS_HUMAN = 'Y' THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS IS_HUMAN_VALUE,
    CASE
        WHEN IS_LIVE IS NULL THEN 'N'
        ELSE IS_LIVE
    END AS IS_LIVE,
    CASE
        WHEN IS_LIVE = 'Y' THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS IS_LIVE_VALUE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.CLIENT,
            A.ACCT,
            A.ACCT_NAME,
            MAX(CASE
                WHEN AF.FUNCTION = 'IS_HUMAN' THEN AF.VALUE
            END) AS IS_HUMAN,
            MAX(CASE
                WHEN AF.FUNCTION = 'IS_LIVE' THEN AF.VALUE
            END) AS IS_LIVE
        FROM
            ACCOUNT A
            LEFT JOIN ACC_FUNCTION AF ON AF.CLIENT = A.CLIENT
                                         AND A.ACCT = AF.ACCT
        GROUP BY
            A.CLIENT,
            A.ACCT,
            A.ACCT_NAME
    )
```

I have created a [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=66ef78f17e3d1e2a32ee3c585537e785) for this.

You can add a `condition of the client column` according to your need.

Hope, This is useful to you.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your solution ,the query i think works well if we are aware of the no of rows on the Account char function.Apologies if not mentioned ,the query would need to be dynamic to take into consideration the account char rows.

Comment: Means, You need it to be dynamic? uummm.. Dynamic number of columns? really?

Comment: Yes really ,i am expectig it to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You want to pivot two values. Add `case` twice to show output in desired format:

```
select client, acct, acct_name, 
       is_human, case is_human when 'Y' then 'Yes' when 'N' then 'No' end is_human_value,
       is_live, case is_live when 'Y' then 'Active' when 'N' then 'Inactive' end is_live_value
  from account a join account_function using (client, acct)
  pivot (max(value) for function in ('Is_Human' is_human, 'Is_Live' is_live))
  order by acct;
```

Result:

```
CLIENT ACCT  ACCT_NAME IS_HUMAN IS_HUMAN_VALUE IS_LIVE IS_LIVE_VALUE
------ ----- --------- -------- -------------- ------- -------------
OK     OK123 OK123_Pnb Y        Yes            Y       Active
OK     OK144 OK144_Bnb N        No             Y       Active
VV     VV510 VV510_Vpk Y        Yes                    
VV     VV553 VV553_Vnb N        No
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1bbec21fe3c1a0172a35f6eeaf4cb3ad)</sup>**

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your answer,but this would need to be dynamic meaning we might be having multiple rows on the account char table.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following PROCEDURE to create a dynamic view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCESS_VW_DATA
IS
   VVIEWCOLUMN   VARCHAR2 (2000) DEFAULT '' ;
   SQL_STMT1     VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      FOR C IN (  SELECT   DISTINCT FUNCT
                    FROM   ACCOUNT_FUNCTION
                ORDER BY   1)
      LOOP
         VVIEWCOLUMN :=
               VVIEWCOLUMN
            || ' '
            || 'MAX (DECODE (FUNCT, '
            || ''''
            || C.FUNCT
            || ''''
            || ', RESULT)) AS '
            || C.FUNCT
            || ', '
            || 'CASE WHEN MAX (DECODE (FUNCT, '
            || ''''
            || C.FUNCT
            || ''''
            || ', RESULT)) = ''Y'' AND UPPER('
            || ''''
            || C.FUNCT
            || ''''
            || ') = ''IS_LIVE'' THEN ''Active''  
                 WHEN COALESCE(MAX (DECODE (FUNCT, '
            || ''''
            || C.FUNCT
            || ''''
            || ', RESULT)),''N'') = ''N'' AND UPPER('
            || ''''
            || C.FUNCT
            || ''''
            || ') = ''IS_LIVE'' THEN ''Inactive'' 
                 WHEN MAX (DECODE (FUNCT, '
            || ''''
            || C.FUNCT
            || ''''
            || ', RESULT)) = ''Y'' AND UPPER('
            || ''''
            || C.FUNCT
            || ''''
            || ') <> ''IS_LIVE'' THEN ''Yes'' 
                ELSE ''No'' END AS '
            || C.FUNCT
            || '_VALUE'
            || ',';
      END LOOP;

      SELECT   DISTINCT SUBSTR (VVIEWCOLUMN, 1, LENGTH (VVIEWCOLUMN) - 1)
        INTO   VVIEWCOLUMN
        FROM   DUAL;
   END;

   BEGIN
      SQL_STMT1 :=
         ' CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS 
                  SELECT   AF.CLIENT,
                           AF.ACCT,
                           ACT.ACCT_NAME,'
         || VVIEWCOLUMN
         || '

                    FROM   ACCOUNT_FUNCTION AF, ACCOUNT ACT
                   WHERE   AF.ACCT = ACT.ACCT
                   GROUP BY   AF.ACCT, AF.CLIENT, ACT.ACCT_NAME
                ORDER BY   1';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STMT1;
   END;
END PROCESS_VW_DATA;
```

Then Execute the procedure:

```
EXEC PROCESS_VW_DATA
```

Now you can run your desired query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_VIEW WHERE CLIENT='OK'
```

If you want to set "Active/Inactive" as status during query then replace the following part of Procedure

```
 VVIEWCOLUMN :=
       VVIEWCOLUMN
    || ' '
    || 'MAX (DECODE (FUNCT, '
    || ''''
    || C.FUNCT
    || ''''
    || ', RESULT)) AS '
    || C.FUNCT
    || ','
    || 'CASE WHEN MAX (DECODE (FUNCT, '
    || ''''
    || C.FUNCT
    || ''''
    || ', RESULT)) = ''Y'' THEN ''Yes'' ELSE ''No'' END AS '
    || C.FUNCT
    || '_VALUE ,';
```

Then set "Active/Inactive" status in your query